# How to add a Bridging-Header to Xcode Playground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, bridging-header

**Is it possible to include ObjectiveC header files using a Bridging-Header file to Xcode Playground?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Can't make a Playground recognize frameworks using `import`, even if this Framework is part of a project with the `Bridging-Header` correctly configured.